# what is the role of __getattr__ and __setattr__ in this piece of code?

Tags: python, getter, setter

I have written singleton pattern in python in this way .It works fine  but i don't understand what the **getattr** and **setattr** exactly do ? what is the difference between getattr() and **getattr** and also between setattr() and **setattr** in python ? does these two methods(**getattr** and **setattr**) do sth to the inner class and how do these two methods distinguish to work on the inner class and not the outer class ? 
thank you in advance.

---

```
class Writer:
    class __file_writer:
        def __init__(self):
            self.variable = None

        def __str__(self):
            return str(id(self))

    instance = None

    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if not Writer.instance :
            Writer.instance = Writer.__file_writer()

        return Writer.instance

    def __getattr__(self, item):
        return getattr(self.instance,item)

    def __setattr__(self, key, value):
        return setattr(self.instance, key,value)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    obj1=Writer()
    obj1.name = 'moli'
    print(obj1.name)
    print(type(obj1))

    obj2 = Writer()
    obj2.name = 'ffff'
    print(obj2.name)
    print(obj1.name)
    print(obj1)
    print(obj2)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**__getattr__** works when you want to lookup an attribute that doesn't exist in this class.

and **__setattr__** when you assign a value to an attribute that doesn't exist in the class
check these two examples

https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/dunderattr/setattr.html#example

https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/dunderattr/getattr.html#example

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't serve any purpose here. Because when you're accessing `name` you're accessing `name` attribute of class `__file_writer` not of class `Writer`.

If you push the `__getattr__` function to `__file_writer` class then you will be able to see the difference how it's being called when you try to access the attribute `name`.

Comment: thank you , if i want to push __getattr__ function to __file_writer class , how can i see the difference how it's being called wheni try to access the attribute name?